# Graph of dsolve

Tags: matlab, function, dsolve

How to plot the following function? I need x range of `[0; 1]`.

```
syms y(x)
y(x) = dsolve(diff(y,x) == tan(x), y(0) == 1);
plot(y, [0 1]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message that you get is:

> Error using plot
>   
> Non-numeric data is not supported in 'Line'

This exactly tells what the problem is. `y` is *not numeric data* here. Rather it is a symbolic function. You need to evaluate `y` at the required points and then plot it.

**Fixed Code:**

```
syms y(x)
y(x) = dsolve(diff(y,x) == tan(x), y(0) == 1);
x=0:0.01:1;
plot(x,y(x));
```

**Output:**

[image: output]

Comment: Thank you. I've read this error. But i'm newb so didn't know what we get by dsolve. And don't know exactly how does plot works.

Comment: @Александр ! if this answer solves your problem then [mark it accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/335102) by clicking the **`✓`** mark on the left side of this answer . Familiarize yourself with the [MATLAB documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/). It is very well written and you can find almost everything in it